# "'/usr/share/app-install/desktop/software-center.menu': Not a directory" error when trying to reinstall the software center

Tags: apt, software-center

I was having some problem with Software center. So tried to reinstall it. But While removing it give me an error.

```
(Reading database ... 150986 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing software-center ...
dpkg: error processing software-center (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/software-center.menu': Not a directory
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-center
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now The same problem is repeating if I use apt-get to install or upgrade my ubuntu.
I cant install any software and Software-Center too.. PLZ help

Comment: `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/software-center.menu` isn't supposed to be a directory, but a file. Try removing it directly: `sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/desktop/software-center.menu` followed by a reinstallation: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center`

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/share/app-install/desktop/software-center.menu` isn't supposed to be a directory, but a file.

Try removing it directly: `sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/desktop/software-center.menu`

Followed by a reinstallation: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center`